# Finding a stationary matrix

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I am having trouble understanding how to answer this question.
I have a transition matrix P:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        .7 & 0 & .3 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        .2 & 0 & .8 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
I've figured out the first part of the question which asked me to prove that two 1x3 matrices were stationary which I did with SP=S.
But for the second part of the question it asks me to find another stationary matrix for P and it provides me with a hint. The hint is:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
  \\T=aR+(1-a)S, \\
 0<a<1
        \end{matrix}
$$

I'm not sure what to do with that equation. Am I supposed to turn it into another 1x3 matrix and prove it's stationary with TP=T? Do I multiply the  equation as it is now with P and then figure out something with that result? Or do I substitute a number in for 'a' and solve for that and then multiply that result with P?

Answer (score 0):

Call one of your given stationary matrices $S$ and call the other one $R$.

The hint is asking you to calculate a linear combination of the two matrices. So pick any value you like for $a$ - perhaps $a=0.5$? and calculate $T$. This will have the property that it is also a stationary matrix.